# Images are not loaded in my HTML site

Tags: html, .htaccess

Can anyone help me? Here is my path to my website.

http://startadvertising.co.in/golfedge/

All the images are in same 'img' folder. But I wonder why some images are loaded while some are not.

Is it any kind of HTACCESS problem? I am really poor in htaccess problems.

I searched for solution but could not find any. I changed folder permissions, file permissions but nothing helped.

Please help me.

Comment: Can anyone at least guess what the problem might be?

Comment: if you are hosting it on linux, keep in mind that the filenames **are** case sensitive. Some of your `.png` files have uppercase extensions, either change the code or the filenames.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the filetype of your images correctly. Some of them are uppercase.

**Example**

Change **"logo.PNG"** to **"logo.png"**

In your HTML you defined the filetypes lowercase:

```
<img id="site-logo" src="img/logo.png">
```

Answer (score 1):

IT's a problem with your extension .png replace that in .PNG in those image which can not show and if you use the .htaccess then change the url